# Ionic 2 not seeing images

Tags: ionic2

Im currently working with Ionic 2.0.0-beta.32. After some searching around, I found the following code to add images to my project then at build time have them auto import into the final build

I add a directory in app called img, and place all my images in there, then the code in the gulpfile is as follows

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src(['app/img/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/build/img'));
});
```

and also all the runSequences

```
runSequence(
['images', 'sass', 'html', 'fonts', 'scripts'],
```

This all works good and moves the images to the `www` at build time, but when i run

```
ionic serve --lab
```

none of the images show, I've tried using the following

```
../img/imgname
/img/imgname
img/imgname
build/img/imgname
```

None of the above shows my image.

Any help would be great, im pulling out my hair here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use Gulp to modify your images (i.e., reduce their sizes) or something like that? If the answer is no, then **you don't need to add that task** to your gulp file

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src(['app/img/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/build/img'));
});
```

Why? Because if the image won't be changed, it doesn't make sense that each time that you run your tasks, the images gets copied again and again (without changes).

A simple way to work with images would be to put your images in a `www\images` folder, and then reference them in your code like this:

```
<img src="images/myImage.png" />
```

Since they're in the `www` folder, they're not going to be deleted (which happens if you place them in the `build` folder of your app).

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot more sense, sorry if the question sounded a bit daft, im new to this

Comment: Are there any guides on how big i should be making my images?

Comment: Glad I could help :) About the sizes, I'm not sure... I guess it's up to which devices is your app going to be use in... we always try to use retina images.

Comment: and size them using css?

Comment: Yeap... but I'm not sure if that's the recommended way to work with the images to be honest.

Comment: Oh really? guess its more investigation for me hahaha ... thank you for your help

Comment: Np, that's why we are all here for :)